# Solution to y+2=y

Tags: proof-explanation, fake-proofs

Recently I saw the following proof:

\begin{align*}(y+2)^2 &= y^2\\
y^2 + 4y + 4 &= y^2\\
4y &= -4\\
y &= -1\\ \end{align*}

Geometrically I see the flaw in this solution. Solving for $y + 2 = y$ is basically asking where the lines $f_1 = y+2$ and $f_2 = y$ intersect? Since these are parallel lines, they never intersect and there is no solution for $y$. Squaring sides changes the equation itself to the intersection of two parabolas. So geometrically squaring both sides is obviously a flaw.

But why is this wrong algebraically? Squaring both sides seems to make sense. Furthermore, could someone give me a list of tips to easily identify the problem with a lot of these false proofs? I seem to be seeing a lot of them.

Comment: Try $\lim\limits _{y\to \infty}$

Comment: $a=b\Rightarrow a^2=b^2$ but $a^2=b^2\not\Rightarrow a= b$, rather $a=+b$ or $a=-b$. So you found that $y+2=-y$ has a solution $y=-1$ but the original equation has no solution.

Comment: Squaring can give extra solutions, it is NOT an equivalence transformation.

Answer (score 6):

$a = b$ implies $a^2 = b^2$. The [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)) is not true. Consider $a = 1, b = -1$.

More technically, squaring is not an [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function): It maps distinct numbers to the same number. Thus it cannot be "undone" or "reversed" in general.